# Android - how to debug trace into native external libraries?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, debugging

I have a dual-mode Android application (Java and JNI native code in C++) that I'm trying to debug. I can debug the application's native code just fine, but when trying to trace into code loaded from statically linked libraries - that are built externally and shipped as `.a` files into the project - Android studio just refuses to step into them.

The libraries `.a` files have embedded debug symbols and I have full source code for the external libraries, but I couldn't figure out how to get Android Studio to recognize that - I've added the directory with the `.a` files to the Run->Edit Configurations->Debugger->Debug Symbols list, but even using "force step into" doesn't step into the external library code.

For comparison, with XCode I can step into an external library function and XCode puts me in  a disassemble trace, and then I can use the lldb console command line to add source maps from the source path recorded in the debug symbols to the location of the source files on my system, and then it just syncs and I can step through the external source code. Its not fun (I have to setup the source map manually, again and again, every time I restart the debug session), but it works.

Is there someway of doing a similar thing with Android Studio? I couldn't find any discussion of this on the internet.

Comment: does your shared library contain the debug symbols? I'm reasonably sure you can't use debug symbols from static libraries

Comment: Usually it is possible to step into code of  both static and dynamic third-party libraries directly, without getting into disassembly or typing any lldb commands. I suspect that the problem is that those libraries are "built externally". You should rebuild them inside of the gradle prject using the same toolchain and same compiler options as your jni library.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - the static libraries have debug symbols: they were built with `-g` and I have verified with `nm` and `readelf`.

Comment: @user7860670 - the whole point is to trace through libraries built externally. I'm using dependencies that are created by a 3rd party, take a long time to build (>1 hour in my CI) and never change - it makes no sense to build them inside my Android project, and this should work - it shouldn't matter if it was built by a different compiler. And again, it works in XCode and other development environments.

Comment: @Guss I'm not disputing that the static libraries have symbols, what I'm not sure of is whether the debugger can use them. I think it might only load them from shared libraries which is why i asked whether the symbols were present in your shared library

Comment: @AlanBirtles - OK, that's actually a very good question, sorry I missed the "shared library" term. Android Studio with CMake builds `.so` files into these dirs under `build/intermediates`: `cmake`, `merged_native_libs`, `stripped_native_libs`, `library_jni`. The first two include debug symbols from the external static libraries, the last two contain no debug symbols from either external libraries or the Android project's C++ code. I can trace through my own C++ code, so I'm assuming that I should also be able to trace through external libiraries.

Comment: I checked using `objdump -Wi` and I can see compile unit paths and line numbers for symbols coming from the external libraries as well as the project's C++ cpde.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing a similar problem when consuming an `.aar` with a bunch of `.a` libraries. Unable to step into those, even though I have the source code a.s.o.